# React events not trigering on mobile but works fine in desktop. I tried onClick,onTouchStart, onTouchEnd, onMouseUp,OnMouseDown

Tags: reactjs

when i try to click the button event itself is not triggering in mobile.I works fine in desktop.

I saw some posts and tried cursor ,z-Index property but nothing works.

```
<div>
     <button  style ={{ cursor: 'pointer', zIndex : 1000 }} 
               onClick={ () => { console.log("ABC")} } >Button</button>
</div>
```

onclick button should print "ABC"

Comment: which mobile phone, iphone, android?

Comment: All mobile devices.Thanks for reaching me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `postion: 'relative'`. The default value is static, to change it from static add position relative.

```
<div>
   <button style={{ cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 1000, position: 'relative' }}
     onClick={() => { console.log("ABC") }} >Button</button>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-55sfe8)

Comment: Thank you junius. It works. Can you explain me what is causing the issue thanks

Comment: z-index needs position to be different than static (which is the default) to work.